# Getting a path of a Stream by converting to FileStream

Tags: c#, stream, filestream

I need to get the path of the original file in the stream.

I read that I need to use the "**Name**" property of the **FileStream** to get it's path.
So far so good.

The problem is I have a regular **System.IO.Stream** and not **FileStream**, and therefore I don't have the "**Name**" property.

I read that there is a **Stream.CopyTo** method: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx`

I planned to convert my **Stream** to **FileStream** like that:

```
System.IO.FileStream fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(?????);
using (stream)
{
    stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

But FileStream has no parameterless constructor.

How can I solve it?

Comment: @RohitVats it is not. the questions is the same, but he got a different solution INSTEAD of converting it to FileStream, which won't work for me. READ THE ANSWERS!!!! I bet you are the downvoter AND the one who suggested to close the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the Stream is an instance of a FileStream you can cast the Stream down to a FileStream:

```
var fileStream = stream as FileStream;
```

The only way you'll be able to get the path name from the Stream instance is if you are able to cast it down to a class that provides a way of accessing the path.

Comment: it worked!! but is it a safe way of doing it? it can't crush or something? what should i expect?

Comment: If the Stream instance is always a FileStream then it's completely safe; fileStream will be null if it's not an instance of FileStream, so check for that if you can't be sure

Answer (score 1):

getting path of stream

```
System.IO.FileStream Stream = ....;
FileStream fs = stream as FileStream;
if (fs != null)
{
    // now you can check its path
}
else
{
    // you cant check its path
}
```